# How to clear phone memory in Windows 10?

Tags: storage, windows-10-mobile

I want to clear the phone memory of my Windows 10 phone, however, phone memory does not show up in storage, it only shows the SD card. In Windows Phone 8.1 we could see both phone memory and SD card, but now there is nothing in my phone memory directories. Might be that all app related data is there in phone memory.

So how can I clear this?

Comment: I assume you're checking via Settings > System > Storage?

Comment: @Shawn Yes i'm doing it.But can only see external storage.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "clear phone memory"? If you mean wiping the entire phone, then that would be achieved by doing a factory reset. Or do you mean deleting certain types of data, like temporary files?

Comment: in latest build update it is available check it

Comment: @SD7 ya it is availble now